# RecyclerView - Get position from ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've a `RecyclerView` implemented with a `GridLayoutManager`, something similar to an Image Gallery. I'm trying to implement a drag select behavior on it using [this library](https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview).

I want to activate the drag selection on a *long press of a view holder*. Below is the sample activation code for the library.

```
touchListener.setIsActive(true, index) // index = start position of the view holder in the grid
```

**Issue:**

I implemented the `OnLongClickListener` on the ViewHolder but how do I get the position of the view in the grid?

```
class ImageViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnLongClickListener {
    override fun onLongClick(v: View): Boolean {
        ImageFragment.activateDragSelect(0) // Calls the above activation snippet
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `getAdapterPosition()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have to position of your `ViewHolder` with:

`getAdapterPosition()`